# Removing json objects from an array stored in postgresql column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have an array of json objects, from which I want to removed three specific objects. 
For example:

```
[{"id": "aaa"}, {"id": "aab"}, {"id": "aac"}, {"id": "aad"}]
```

I need to update the table and remove from the array the objects that contain `"aaa"`, `"aab"`, and `"aac"` so that the array would only contain

```
[{"id": "aad"}]
```

or whatever other json objects that are stored in the array and don't contain the previous mentioned values stored in "id".

I'm using Postgres, and I know just that I need to use UPDATE, but that's about it (I'm still a beginner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array, filter out the unwanted elements and then aggregate back:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = (select jsonb_agg(j)
                     from jsonb_array_elements(the_table.the_column) as t(j)
                     where j ->> 'id' not in ('aaa','aab','aac'));
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/HCJK50138